# Not starting after installation

Tags: 14.04

I was using a 32 bit computer with Windows XP, recently i faced issues with XP and it crashed , as my original CD was corrupted, I could not reinstall it, I thought of giving ubuntu a try. 
I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 and installed by replacing win-xp, Installation was fine but after restarting ubuntu could not load. Now I am writing this with the option try Ubuntu.

With regards
Merwyn

Comment: Please ask a question and give details as to what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please supply more details.  Did a purple looking boot loader called GRUB appear?  Did you have a black screen after that?  Did anything give an error?